# Cannot access the file from server using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, cordova

I am new in phonegap app development. I want to create an app that will communicate (CRUD operations) with server. I have created a json using php. now I want to access that file using angularJS. But can't access that file ("http://apptest.byethost5.com/view.php") from server. But localhost gives me the correct result. I think there has some permission problem to that file. I have changed the file permission to 755 but that does not work. Can you please suggest the correct way to deal with this problem.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
            <td>{{ x.firstname }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.lastname }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $http.get("http://apptest.byethost5.com/view.php")
     .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
 });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the page being requested is on a different server, then for security reasons that server must explicitly allow cross-origin requests

Add this to the top of view.php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")
```

Comment: If you don't want to allow requests from any domain, be sure to replace * in the above with your specific requesting domain.